# Authentication and Authorization in Razor Page by JWT and Google

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, authentication, authorization, razor-pages

I have a project using google authen and i want to use JWT to authorization without using Identity. It is doesn't work, although I saw a lot of tutorials. This is my code, where is it wrong?
This is the config in Program (I wrote app.Use correctly):

```
builder.Services
.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    //options.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultSignInScheme = "Cookies";
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
})
.AddCookie("Cookies")
.AddJwtBearer(options =>
{
    options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
    {
        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
        IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8
            .GetBytes(builder.Configuration.GetSection("AppSettings:Token").Value)),
        ValidateIssuer = false,
        ValidateAudience = false,
    };
})
.AddGoogle(
     options =>
    {
        IConfiguration googleAuthen = builder.Configuration.GetSection("Authentication:Google");
        options.SaveTokens = true;
        options.ClientId = googleAuthen["ClientId"];
        options.ClientSecret = googleAuthen["ClientSecret"];
        options.CorrelationCookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.Lax;
    }
);
```

Code in LoginModel:

```
        public IActionResult OnPostLoginByGoogle()
    {
        string authenticationScheme = GoogleDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;

        var auth = new AuthenticationProperties
        {
            RedirectUri = Url.Page("/Login", pageHandler: "LoginGoogleCallback")
        };

        return new ChallengeResult(authenticationScheme, auth);
    }

    public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetLoginGoogleCallbackAsync()
    {
        var authenticateResult = await HttpContext.AuthenticateAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);

        if (!authenticateResult.Succeeded)
            return BadRequest(); // TODO: Handle this better.

        var userId = authenticateResult.Principal.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier);
        var userEmail = authenticateResult.Principal.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.Email);

        UserDTO loginedUser = _userRepository.GetUserByEmail((string)userEmail);
        
        string token = CreateToken(loginedUser);

        return RedirectToPage("/Students/TimeTable");

        //return LocalRedirect("/test");
    }

    public string CreateToken(UserDTO user)
    {
        List<Claim> claims = new List<Claim>
        {
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, user.Email),
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "Student"),
        };
        var key = new SymmetricSecurityKey(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(
            _configuration.GetSection("AppSettings:Token").Value));
        var cred = new SigningCredentials(key, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha512Signature);
        
        var token = new JwtSecurityToken(
            claims: claims,
            expires: DateTime.Now.AddDays(1),
            signingCredentials: cred
            );
        var jwt = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(token);
        
        return jwt;
    }
```

and in the another Page I wrote `[Authorize(Roles = "Student")]` and the result when directing to that page is HTTP 401 unAuthorized (I was assigning ClaimTypes.Role = Student to test easily)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your Code, After you use `CreateToken` method to generate a token, You redirect to the target page directly without carrying that token, So even you configure `ClaimTypes.Role = Student` in your token, You will also get 401 error. What you need to do is make sure the request carries the generated token.

One of the methods is create a middleware. In this middleware, You can get token from session, Then add this token to your request header.

```
            app.UseSession();

            //add token to request header.
            app.Use(async (context, next) =>
            {
                var token = context.Session.GetString("Token");
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(token))
                {
                    context.Request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);
                }
                await next();
            });

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();

            app.UseAuthentication();
            
            app.UseAuthorization();
```

In your `OnGetLoginGoogleCallbackAsync` method, After generate token, save this token in session.

```
string token = CreateToken(loginedUser);
HttpContext.Session.SetString("Token",token);
return RedirectToPage("/Students/TimeTable");
```

Comment: Oh, I am still a newbie, so I often get stuck in some problems. Thank you very much for your answer.

Comment: You are welcome, If you meet any problems in your develpoment, You can ask it in StackOver Flow.